# How do I print multiple variables on the same line in the DolphinDB GUI?

Tags: printing, dolphindb, gui-designer

I want to print the following variables on the same line:

```
print('pre_date', pre_date, 'date', date)
```

Execute the script in GUI and the **output** is:

```
pre_date
2021.01.06T00:00:00.000000000
date
2021.01.06T00:00:00.000000000
```

The result is displayed on 4 separate lines. How to output them on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plus sign (“+”) to concatenate strings together and print it out:

```
print('pre_date:' + string(pre_date) + ',date:' + string(date))
```